# Django - Autocompleting fields when re-rendering form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

In my project, I have a Django form, which I then pass to my template. This form allows users to Signup for an account.

If the user makes a mistake, I use **Django messages** to return an error to the user, and then redirect to the same page with the error. This error is successfully displayed.

However all the previous data the user entered into the form is lost. What I want is too reload the page with the form filled in with all the previous data the user entered. This way they can correct the data easily without having to re-enter all the information again.

Does Anybody know how to accomplish this? Thank you.

**views.py:**

```
    if form.cleaned_data['password'] != form.cleaned_data['confirmPassword']:
        messages.error(request, 'Password fields do not match')
        return redirect('signup')
    else:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
            messages.error(request, 'Username has already been taken') 
            return redirect('signup')
```

Template:

```
{% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                 <span  class="errorMessageSignup"> <img src="{% static 'wrongcross.png' %}" style="position:absolute;" height="17px" width="17px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>{{ message }}</b></span>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: You should just re-render the same template with the invalid form - invalid forms in DJango have error messages attached to them for just this case

Comment: @IainShelvington Ok thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this in your template where you have form .

```
 <input type="text" name="username" {% if form.username.value %} value="{{form.username.value}}" {% endif %}>
 <input type="password" name="password" {% if form.password.value %} value="{{form.password.value}}" {% endif %}>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the username and password data and pass them to the template wherever you render it. 
[This little guide should help you :)](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/dynamic_data_in_templates/)

Comment: This is not what I want. The username and password data the user enters will be invalid, so I want to redisplay the form with this invalid data, so they can correct it. Therefore I do not want anything saving into a database. Do you know a solution for this? Thank you.